# How can I round a value to the closest number in an array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code and explanation:

```cs
public void Update()
{ 
    double[] array = new double[] {37.5, -87.5};
    var CPos = 41.30329;
    var RoundedNumber = // The closest number CPos can round to in the array, in this case it would be 37.5
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Pre-sort the array in descending order, and then find the first item that CPos is `<=` to.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that CPOS is a changing number so sometimes it could be -8 or 108 etc. How might I sort the array?

Comment: `var closest = array.Select(z = new { diff = Math.Abs(Cos - z), z}).MinBy(z => z.diff).Select(z => z).First();` `MinBy` is from MoreLinq.

Comment: Or even better - `var closest = array.MinBy(z => Math.Abs(Cos - z)).First();`

Comment: You can sort the whole list, then binary search index pos of the element bigger or equal to CPos, then round it to a[pos] or a[pos - 1] if it exists.

Comment: in my code the "MinBy" is underlined red and says Double[] does not contain the defenition MinBy

Comment: I fixed that by adding System.Linq; and System; but now Cos has an error

Comment: I think Cos was a typo and meant to be CPos

Comment: @Llama I thought so to but if I correct it to CPos the .First() becomes underlined red

Comment: Did you add `MoreLinq` like I mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this for anyone who wants to know:

```
var RoundedNumber = array.OrderBy(v => Math.Abs((long)v - CPos)).First();
```

Comment: what is the cast to `long` good for? This cuts off the decimals and thereby can have incorrect results e.g. for `{0.05f, 0.04f, 0.02f}` and `CPos = 0.023f`  ;)

Comment: The `MinBy` approach I suggested would use less memory and be faster. But will net the same result.